# How to fix 404 issues after removing category

Tags: wordpress

This is actually an SEO question. I do know quite a bit of SEO but in this case, it's to do with 404's being created across my website. Essentially the WordPress site has left a string of pages not found. The initial installation used the "category" prefix, and now as that has been removed, I have tonnes of 404's popping up. What is the best way to deal with these as there is pagination for each category and there may be hundreds of errors? Making individual 301's does not seem like the best option. And I do not think using regex will work as that redirects to the root address, right? Thanks, everyone for your time.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just set redirect 301 from your category slug to another page

if your category slug is `news`, so set a regular expression for all posts that they were in this category and redirect this pattern to another page or post or ....

Just do it in Yoast SEO

from: `yoursite/news/[a-zA-z0-9]`

to: `yoursite/anotherPage`

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply. How to deal with pagination issue, as it's not a single post. There may be hundreds of paginated posts category/mma/page/3 - category/mma/page/303. So now I have to create individual 301's for each page? Can this be solved using some regex option? I'm not very certain. Apart from being a lot of work, making now an individual 301's seems like unnecessary redirect bloating as search engines have to comb through the database to find the new 301's, thanks.